# Angular2 – Component instantiation issue with Router usage

Tags: angular2-routing

**Angular2 – Component re-instantiation problem**

I am newbie in Angular2 world.

I have been trying to load component via angualr2 router. It works absolutely fine. The problem arise when we visit the router-link which was already visited before.

**Problem Scenario is as follows,**

We have two router link with Component Home and About respectively.

> *Home – About*

On component ngOnInit(), I catch every controls defined in it's Templates and place it inside DOM via some Javascripts like

> **document.getElementById (“test”).insertAdjacentElement(“beforeEnd”, Element from Component’s Template)**.

When you click first time on both the links component is correctly rendered but on second click on **Home** Angular2 component doesn’t instantiate again.

How can we enforce Component to instantiate each time when link is clicked?